# Java JDBC connect to Microsoft SQL - No Connection but no errors

Tags: sql-server-2008, jdbc

im nearly becoming crazy :)

I installed a Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 im my network and now im tryin to connect the sql database via JAVA JDBC. Im using the Microsoft JDBC Driver v3 the sqljdbc4.jar ( http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/de-de/details.aspx?FamilyID=a737000d-68d0-4531-b65d-da0f2a735707 )

Java Code:

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.1.144:1433;database=mydatabase;user=root;password=root");
//this line is not even printed so the problem have to be at getConnection
System.out.println("test");
```

The strange thing is that there is no exception appearing. Its just doing nothing. If I try it with a wrong username there is a exception so the authentication seems to work.

Maybe there is afirewall problem wich blocks the connection from the java client (OS of the server is MS Server 2008R2) ?

Hope some of you guys have an idea what can be the problem or a approach to solve this. Thanks in advance ...

Comment: I think you are missing the `instanceName` from the connection string

Comment: Thx for your reply ...

But it wasnt the instance:
I tried:

`Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.1.144\\WIN-JRVO6I57T5V:1433;;loginTimeout=20;database=Studienprojekt;user=root;password=root");`

as well as 

`Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.1.144:1433;instanceName=WIN-JRVO6I57T5V;loginTimeout=20;database=Studienprojekt;user=root;password=root");`

In the JDBC Documentation they say that if there is no instance mentioned it will use the default one. I think thats the correct one in my case ...

Comment: So I tried the script running directly on the server with localhost as server name and it worked like charme. 

So there must be a right-policy problem with the sql server or the firewall of the microft server ... im not really into the server stuff so maybe some of you guys have an idea where to look ...

Comment: Java Update to v7 solved that Problem ... thx

Answer (score 1):

Glad you were able to connect.  If you were using Sun Java 6 update 29 there was a bug that prevented connections.  Sun fixed the bug in the subsequent update 6 update 30.  We are in the process of testing JRE 7 against the Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server.  You can find the latest status here - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jdbcteam/archive/2011/11/07/supported-java-versions-november-2011.aspx